# Setting Windows Service's Status

Tags: c#, windows-services, status

I'm trying to create a windows service that runs an exe that I have. I have been using [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#BK_CreateProject) from msdn.

I run my exe as a `Process` that is started in `OnStart` and stopped in `OnStop`.
I want to know how the service status, the status `sc query *name*`, is updated.

I've tried following the status section, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#BK_SetStatus), of the guide above, but calling

```
serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED;
SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
```

and those type of functions from the guide don't seem to do anything.

I want to be able to set the status of the service to be stopped, if my exe that the service runs crashes or is killed.

One idea I have in mind is to have a separate function that is run in a thread from `OnStart` that will block using `process.WaitForExit();`. And after thread stops blocking, I wanted to use the functions above to set the service status as stopped.

Does anyone have any idea on why I can't set the service status, or how to link the service status to the exe that the service runs? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not set the service status. It sounds like you should stop your service when the exe crashes or is killed.
To stop the service, use ServiceBase.Stop()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx

This will change the service status to stopped.